# django : create a HTML alert based on ModelForm fields?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on `user-leaves-managing-system`

`models.py`

```
CHOICES = (('Earned Leave','Earned Leave'),('Casual Leave','Casual Leave'),('Sick Leave','Sick Leave'),('Paid Leave','Paid Leave'))
class User(models.Model)    

     type_of_leave = models.CharField(max_length = 15, choices = CHOICES)
     from_date = models.DateField()
     to_date = models.DateField()
```

`forms.py`

```
class RequestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ( "type_of_leave", "from_date", "to_date")
        model = Leave

        widgets =  {

            'from_date' : DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}),
            'to_date' : DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}),
                   }
```

`views.py`

```
def leaveRequest(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LeaveRequestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            leave = form.save(commit = False)
            leave.user = request.user
            form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/thanks/")
    else:
        ...
```

The user applies for a leave, for each type of leave I have given a default value of `10 days` in the db through the `admin`. So, if the user applies for more than the leaves he have I want to generate an HTML alert with a message, i.e if the leaves are used off to the fullest or `becomes = 0`.

So I'm confused where and how to define it.

I have put this in my forms.py under `RequestForm` class yet it didn't work.

```
def clean(self):

        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        to_date = cleaned_data.get("to_date")
        from_date = cleaned_data.get("from_date")

        if from_date < to_date:
            pass
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "From Date should be lesser than To Date "
            )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! So each user has 10 days for leave for each type, so he could have 0 in one and 5 in other? Is that correct?

Comment: @guillermochamorro yes, so if he applied for 3 days of earned leaves with 0 days balance, I need to generate an alert.

Comment: it look like wrong exception calling. it should be `raise forms.ValidationErrror('...')`

Comment: @Kaushal that's a typo. I've updated. yet no use

Comment: You didn't handle `else` part of `form.is_valid()` you suppose to return page with forms erorrs

Comment: @Kaushal Could you please answer it below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Take a look.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    # Everything as before.
    ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        cc_myself = cleaned_data.get("cc_myself")
        subject = cleaned_data.get("subject")

        if cc_myself and subject:
            # Only do something if both fields are valid so far.
            if "help" not in subject:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    "Did not send for 'help' in the subject despite "
                    "CC'ing yourself."
                )
```

Comment: I use ModelForm

Comment: You can use [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform) to validate your modelform instance.